# Automatically remove deleted entity from all collections referencing it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible, when using Hibernate and cascade delete, to remove the cascade-deleted entity from all other entities that have a reference to it?

Take this diagram for example:

[image]

`User` has a `MembershipOffer` to join a `Group`. In my model is possible to remove groups with pending offers, and when that happens, I want all the offers of the deleted group to be deleted as well.

I understand that in order to do that, I will need to change the `MembershipOffer-Group` association to be bidirectional and set the `cascade` flag on it. However, when MembershipOffer is deleted, what happens to the `User`'s reference to it?

I assume Hibernate won't go through every reference to the deleted object and remove it from appropriate collections. Will I have to delete the references manually, or is there a automatic way to do it?

**Note:** 
I am using a relational database and from purely SQL-based look I don't see a problem. `MembershipOffer` table contains FK of both User and Group. When Group is deleted, so are all Offers containing its FK. With their removal the link between Offer and User is deleted. The problem I have is that in the code `User` has a field `Set<MembershipOffer> membershipOffers` which may contain a reference to the just-deleted Offer (which will be invalid if I try to access it).

Comment: Do you have users and their offers already loaded in the session when deleting the MembershipOffer, and do you access their membership offers after the deletion, in the same session? If not, there is nothing to do. If yes, then you should remove the memberhip offer from the list before deleting it.

Comment: Does session equal transaction in this case? The app is communicating via REST - does each request mean one session, or is there a scenario where multiple requests would span one session?

Comment: That all depends on how your code and configuration looks like. But if you do things the usual, default, Spring way, then yes, there is one transaction per session, and each transaction opens its own new session.

Comment: I am trying to stick to the spring way, so hopefully yes. A controller method will perform an authentication and then call an appropriate transactional service/api method, so I guess that should be okay.